# Display out of range (ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) when switching from two monitors to one

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

My system: Dell XPS 8700 with a GeForce GT 635 display controller, 24 Gb RAM, running ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
I have a three monitor setup where this system shares a middle monitor with my work computer; there is an HDMI switcher that can switch the middle monitor to be the 2nd monitor with my work laptop or to be the 2nd monitor for my home desktop.

Until a couple of weeks ago, everything was working okay. I changed my primary home desktop monitor to be a Pixio PX277 Prime 27 inch 165Hz IPS HDR WQHD 2560 x 1440 Wide Screen Display 1440p 165Hz 144Hz Flat FreeSync Esports, 27 inch Gaming Monitor. When I did this, I ran into the display "Out of range" error. It took a while to debug this, but I somehow got this configured to where it worked okay (interestingly, this always worked fine in Windows, but I initially ran into "out of range" errors on the Linux side during boot up and after boot-up).

Then, after an update, the Pixio would display "out of range" errors and shut off IF I was only using one monitor (middle monitor switched to the work PC). If I switched the middle monitor (Ancor Communications Inc 24") to be the 2nd home desktop monitor, then both displays worked fine.

Ideally, I would run both in a 1920x1080 (16:9) resolution (currently the middle monitor is set to 60 Hz; the Pixio can be set from anything 144 Hz to 25.02 Hz). Unfortunately, I can no longer find a mode for the Pixio that will work in single monitor mode. Not sure what had changed in the SW update.

Any advice on what I might try next?

I am otherwise forced to run in Win 10 mode :-(

**EDIT**

```
[~] 505> xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 330mm
   3840x2160     29.97 +  25.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080    144.00   119.88   100.00    59.94*   50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1360x768      59.66  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.99    59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
```

Comment: Could you provide `xrandr -q` command output? Maybe you need to set monitor's mode with `xoutput` command?

Comment: I've added the xrandr -q output to the post. Thanks.